# Another "launch program from terminal" question

Tags: command-line

Answers from previous question are not working for me. When I type:

```
simplenote
./simplenote
./simplenote-1.0.8
/home/quazipseudo/Desktop/simplenote-1.0.8
./home/quazipseudo/Desktop/simplenote-1.0.8
```

I get: `bash: ... No such file or directory`

Only when I type

```
/home/quazipseudo/Desktop/simplenote
```

do I get: `bash: ... Is a directory`

and for:

```
simplenote-1.0.8
```

I get: `command not found` (without the bash)

What am I missing?

Comment: When you type a command, the system searches a set of directories listed in $PATH. Your /home is not in $PATH. The command must exactly match the name of the file, including case.

Comment: Would be also nice if you pointed out "previous answers" that didn't work for you. Please add a few links to those

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I didn't have the right path name. I needed:

```
/home/quazipseudo/Desktop/simplenote/simplenote
```

or

```
/home/quazipseudo/Desktop/simplenote/simplenote.exe
```

Answer (score 3):

The fact that you're trying to run `simplenote` from giving shell a path, tells me that you downloaded `tar.gz` archive and extracted it in your home directory. As such, you probably should have added `/home/quazipseudo/Desktop/simplenote` to list of directories in your `PATH` variable. Simply do

```
$ echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/home/quazipseudo/Desktop/simplenote" >> ~/.bashrc
```

Then log out and log back in.

However, this is not even necessary. [Simplenote download page](https://simplenote.com) clearly shows there is `.deb` installer, and you can download that and install with `dpkg -i ~/Downloads/archive_name.deb`. The `dpkg` installer will  throw all files into directories and places where they belong, and once that is done you should be able to call simplenote from terminal just like that.

If you insist on using `tar.gz` archive, follow my steps:

1. I've downloaded the archive `Simplenote-linux-x64.1.0.8.tar.gz` and once download finished, `cd` into the directory where it's saved. In my case `~/Downloads`.
2. Do `tar -xzvf ./Simplenote-linux-x64.1.0.8.tar.gz` to extract everything.
3. Once extraction is done, there appears `Simplenote-linux-x64/` directory in my `~/Downloads`
4. the file that we want is `Simplenote-linux-x64/Simplenote`. Execute `./Simplenote-linux-x64/Simplenote` from `~/Downloads` and the login screen for Simplenote appears.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if your file is executable.

You can do `ls -al` in the directory and you will see if there is an X in the permissions of the file. If you don't have an x in the permissions, you should do `chmod +x yourfile`

Otherwise, if this still doesn't work you should try doing `sh /path/to/file/with/filename` and it might execute the program.

If it still doesn't work, the file is simply just not a program and can't be run

Comment: If file wasn't executable, it would throw `./simplenote: Permission denied` error.  Running `sh /path/to/file` is OK, but should be used with caution - if the file is a script made for say python or perl, that method won't work. If it's bash script and you're trying to run it with `sh` which is symlinked to `dash` on Ubuntu - that will break because  bash scripts have syntax often incompatible with `dash`.  There's lots to consider

Comment: It is executable: (Type: executable (application/x-executable)) although the file name is only simplenote without the .exe . I use the program a lot by clicking on the tray icon shortcut. the sh and chmod don't seem to work:

sh: 0: Can't open /home/quazipseudo/Desktop/simplenote-1.0.8
chmod: cannot access 'simplenote-1.0.8': No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access 'simplenote': No such file or directory

I'll try the ls -al, but I don't know what that is. I'll have to figure it out.

Comment: I got it! I didn't have the entire path name. I needed /home/quazipseudo/Desktop/**simplenote/simplenote**